# Matlab - Registration and Cropping of aligned images from two different sources

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Good day,

In MATLAB, I have multiple image-pairs of various samples. The images in a pair are taken by different cameras.  The images are in differing orientations, though I have created transforms (for each image-pair) that can be applied to correct that. Their bounds contain the same physical area, but one image has smaller dimensions (ie. 50x50 against 250x250).  Additionally, the smaller image is not in a consistent location within the larger image. However, the smaller image is within the borders of the larger image.

What I'd like to do is as follows: after applying my pre-determined transform to the larger image, I want to crop the part of the larger image that is of the same as the smaller image.

I know I can specify `XData` and `YData` when applying my transforms to output a subset of the transformed image, but I don't know how to relate that to the location of the smaller image. (Note: Transforms were created from control-point structures)

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing how you are specifying control points to get the transformation from one image to another, I'm assuming this is a **registration problem**.  As such, I'm also assuming you are using `imtransform` to warp one image to another.

`imtransform` allows you to specify two additional output parameters:

```
[out, xdata, ydata] = imtransform(in, tform);
```

Here, `in` would be the smaller image and `tform` would be the transformation you created to register the smaller image to warp into the larger image.  You don't need to specify the `XData` and `YData` inputs here.  The inputs of `XData` and `YData` will **bound** where you want to do the transformation.  Usually people specify the dimensions of the image to ensure that the output image is always contained within the borders of the image.  However in your case, I don't believe this is necessary.

The output variable `out` is the warped and transformed image that is dictated by your `tform` object.  The other two output variables `xdata` and `ydata` are the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` values within your co-ordinate system that will encompass the transformed image fully.  As such, you can use these variables to help you locate *where exactly* in the larger image the transformed smaller image appears.  If you want to do a comparison, you can use these to crop out the larger image and see how well the transformation worked.

**NB:** Sometimes the limits of `xdata` and `ydata` will go beyond the dimensions of your image.  However, because you said that the smaller image will always be contained within the larger image (I'm assuming fully contained), then this shouldn't be a problem.  Also, the limits may also be floating point so you'll need to be careful here if you want to use these co-ordinates to crop a minimum spanning bounding box.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct.  Thank you very much for your assistance.